# Find the x,y index of a value in a vector of vectors - C++

Tags: c++, vector

As above, how to find the x and y index of a value in a vector of vectors. 
i.e:

```
Vector of Vectors A :
[[1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,0,B,C],
 [A,D,E,F]]

In[0] : 3

Out[0] : [0,3]
```

The goal is to be able to access the array using its index and get neighboring values.

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to do. Given an index input, you want to find that value in the array and do what?

Comment: Will the value be unique? What if not?

Comment: are these just nested lists?

Comment: @James Sorry. Massive mistake. Added python as a tag when its actually supposed to be C++. The problem of working with two languages at once.

Comment: @schwobaseggl - the values will be unique. That's already taken care of.

Comment: @SaranshMalik - The input is a value that is in the vector of vectors, and the output is the two index needed to access it.

Comment: :D, changing the tag from `python` to `c++` is quite significant!

Comment: @schwobaseggl - Yes, unfortunately, stressed, working in two languages, and being a general beginner is not a good combination. Sorry about that.

Comment: "Neighboring values" meaning what exactly? the values to the left and right of the one used in the index? or display the vector that your index is part of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a simple loop should work. Horribly in-efficient though.

Target is the value you are looking for while arr is the array you are looking for it in.

```
int x = -1; int y = -1;
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.size() ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++ ){
        if(arr[i][j] == target){
            x = i ; y = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(x != -1 && y != -1)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @FantasticMrFox - Thanks. Somehow didn't think of that.